# Inner joins with zend models

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Having problems with this script:

```
$select = $tabela->select()
                     ->joinInner('pedidos_itens', 'pedidos.peIp = pedidos_itens.ipPedido', array('ipProduto', 'ipQtde', 'ipCor', 'ipTextura', 'ipTamanho', 'ipSeq'))
                     ->joinInner('representantes_m', 'pedidos.peRepresentante = representantes_m.rpId', array('rpNome', 'rpTelefone', 'rpCidade', 'rpEstado', 'rpEmail'))
                     ->joinInner('produtos_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipPedido = produtos_m.prId', array('prTitulo', 'prRef', 'prCategoria', 'prColecao'))
                     ->joinInner('produtos_cores_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipProduto = produtos_cores_m.pcProduto', array('pcTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('texturas_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipProduto = texturas_m.teProduto', array('teTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('colecoes_m', 'produtos_m.prColecao = colecoes_m.coId', array('coTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('categorias_m', 'produtos_m.prCategoria = categorias_m.caId', array('caTitulo'))
                     ->where('pedidos.peId = 2')
                     ->order('pedidos.peId DESC');
```

That returns this error:

```
Warning: Select query cannot join with another table in C:\Arquivos de programas\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Select.php on line 1345
```

------- EDIT

I've changed that to this:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    $select = $db->select()
                     ->from('pedidos', array('peId', 'peRepresentante', 'peData', 'peStatus'))
                     ->joinInner('pedidos_itens', 'pedidos.peId = pedidos_itens.ipPedido', array('ipProduto', 'ipQtde', 'ipCor', 'ipTextura', 'ipTamanho', 'ipSeq'))
                     ->joinInner('representantes_m', 'pedidos.peRepresentante = representantes_m.rpId', array('rpNome', 'rpTelefone', 'rpCidade', 'rpEstado', 'rpEmail'))
                     ->joinInner('produtos_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipPedido = produtos_m.prId', array('prTitulo', 'prRef', 'prCategoria', 'prColecao'))
                     ->joinInner('produtos_cores_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipProduto = produtos_cores_m.pcProduto', array('pcTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('texturas_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipProduto = texturas_m.teProduto', array('teTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('colecoes_m', 'produtos_m.prColecao = colecoes_m.coId', array('coTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('categorias_m', 'produtos_m.prCategoria = categorias_m.caId', array('caTitulo'))
                     ->where('pedidos.peId = 2')
                     ->order('pedidos.peId DESC');

    $resultado = $db->query($select)->fetchAll();
```

It returns an empty array, even having records. So? :/

---- EDIT 2

This is the query:

SELECT `pedidos`.`peId`, `pedidos`.`peRepresentante`, `pedidos`.`peData`, `pedidos`.`peStatus`, `pedidos_itens`.`ipProduto`, `pedidos_itens`.`ipQtde`, `pedidos_itens`.`ipCor`, `pedidos_itens`.`ipTextura`, `pedidos_itens`.`ipTamanho`, `pedidos_itens`.`ipSeq`, `representantes_m`.`rpNome`, `representantes_m`.`rpTelefone`, `representantes_m`.`rpCidade`, `representantes_m`.`rpEstado`, `representantes_m`.`rpEmail`, `produtos_cores_m`.`pcTitulo`, `texturas_m`.`teTitulo`, `produtos_m`.`prTitulo`, `produtos_m`.`prRef`, `produtos_m`.`prCategoria`, `produtos_m`.`prColecao`, `colecoes_m`.`coTitulo`, `categorias_m`.`caTitulo` FROM `pedidos`
 INNER JOIN `pedidos_itens` ON pedidos.peId = pedidos_itens.ipPedido
 INNER JOIN `representantes_m` ON pedidos.peRepresentante = representantes_m.rpId
 INNER JOIN `produtos_cores_m` ON pedidos_itens.ipProduto = produtos_cores_m.pcProduto
 INNER JOIN `texturas_m` ON pedidos_itens.ipProduto = texturas_m.teProduto
 INNER JOIN `produtos_m` ON pedidos_itens.ipProduto = produtos_m.prId
 INNER JOIN `colecoes_m` ON produtos_m.prColecao = colecoes_m.coId
 INNER JOIN `categorias_m` ON produtos_m.prCategoria = categorias_m.caId WHERE (pedidos.peId = 2) ORDER BY `pedidos`.`peId` DESC

Comment: do die($select); and copy past the query in phpmyadmin to debug it.

Comment: echo $select; Now you should debug the query. echo it and run it in phpmyadmin or some admin tool

Comment: who knows how the data is in your tables? what is the query o/p in the phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    $select = $db->select()
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE); //Now it will join

                     ->from('pedidos', array('peId', 'peRepresentante', 'peData', 'peStatus'))
                     ->joinInner('pedidos_itens', 'pedidos.peId = pedidos_itens.ipPedido', array('ipProduto', 'ipQtde', 'ipCor', 'ipTextura', 'ipTamanho', 'ipSeq'))
                     ->joinInner('representantes_m', 'pedidos.peRepresentante = representantes_m.rpId', array('rpNome', 'rpTelefone', 'rpCidade', 'rpEstado', 'rpEmail'))
                     ->joinInner('produtos_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipPedido = produtos_m.prId', array('prTitulo', 'prRef', 'prCategoria', 'prColecao'))
                     ->joinInner('produtos_cores_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipProduto = produtos_cores_m.pcProduto', array('pcTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('texturas_m', 'pedidos_itens.ipProduto = texturas_m.teProduto', array('teTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('colecoes_m', 'produtos_m.prColecao = colecoes_m.coId', array('coTitulo'))
                     ->joinInner('categorias_m', 'produtos_m.prCategoria = categorias_m.caId', array('caTitulo'))
                     ->where('pedidos.peId = 2')
                     ->order('pedidos.peId DESC');

    $resultado = $db->query($select)->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use join for table object. you should do using adapter

So, you should use

```
$tabela->getAdapter()->select()
```

and you should use from method

```
 $tabela->getAdapter()->select()->from($this, array())
```

Comment: echo $select; Now you should debug the query. echo it and run it in phpmyadmin or some admin tool

Comment: It is possible to join using a DbTable, you just need to add `->setIntegrityCheck(false)` after the `select()`.